# Redis key storing wrong date as a value

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis-cluster, elastic-cache

When trying in local redis key storing correct date from db but when I run on my dev environment the redis key storing a wrong dates.
(Initially picking data from db if hashkey does not exist.)
eg.
In both cases keys are unique. Hashmap is being used to store cache mapKey =test hashvalue stored as JSON

1. Local: hashkey =X Date in db 27-05-2022 mapkeyJson contain date 27-05-2022
   as JSON
2. Dev Env: hashkey =Y Date in db 27-05-2022 mapkeyJson contain date 26-05-2022

Did anyone faced any similar issue with cache or any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, you should check the timezone of the redis server once and try to match with the db timezone.

Comment: Initially I also suspected same thing but I tested at a time when the timezone having same date... but sure I will check once... thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Update: This issue got resolved by correcting the server timezone.